# How to change type of property via docorators

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator, angular-decorator

I have an angular component like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

function ConvertToBoolean<T extends object, K extends keyof T>() {
  return (target: Object, key: string): void => {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      set(this: T, initialValue: T[K] | K) {
        let currentValue = initialValue;

        Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
          get(): boolean {
            return !!currentValue;
          },
          set(this: T, value: T[K]) {
            currentValue = value;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ConvertToBoolean()
  title: string = "CodeSandbox";

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.title);
    this.title = false; // error
    this.title = "false"; // pass
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `ConvertToBoolean` decorator is changing any property to a boolean value.
But I want to change the type of `title` from `string` to `boolean` in AppComponent class, but I don't know that is possible.

In this code I receive an error:
[image: error ss]

Can you tell me how to do this or is there any information on whether it is possible to obtain it?

I don't found any information about it on google. I only find a class decorator to change a type of constructor property, but this does not solve my problem.

You can also see my code on [this demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-type-via-decorator-owktq?file=/src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: You almost certainly can't do this because the decorator runs at runtime but the type analysis happens at compile time. But you realistically *really don't want this*. It violates the principle of least surprise: now instead of 1 place to look for the type there are n places. It would almost certainly trigger performance-cratering deopts in the JIT. It violates the semantics of the domain names, why would 'title' be a boolean? etc etc. It's just a bad idea.

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881); it's a long discussion, but basically no, TypeScript doesn't let you do this with property decorators.  The TS folks are [probably not going to touch decorators until their JS proposal stabilizes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881#issuecomment-608420023) and so things are stuck the way the are for a while.  Not sure there are any workarounds you'd find palatable.

Answer (score -1):

We can be simpler...

Define your variable with two types:

```js
let variable:boolean | string;
```

Check it on typescript playground.: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAbghgTgSxgI1ALmQe06GA7CAHwgGcxE8BzAbgChbZEVQIBeCcgVxDsaVRBsIAIjAgyw3vH4t2ARjl0gA

Comment: I know I can work it out this way. In my project, it would be more appropriate to use decorators to change the whole type instead of adding another. But thank you