# Typescript Parsing error: Expression expected

Tags: typescript, nestjs-swagger

Please check out this code

```
class A<T = any> {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Success' })
  message: string;
  @ApiProperty({})
  data: T;
}

export const SwaggerEssentials = <T>(okRes?: apiOkResponse) => {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiResponse({ type: A<T>, status: 200 }), // The error is popping up here
  );
};
```

The error is popping up when I try to use `T` with `A` generic value.

Comment: This question seems very similar to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68823518/how-to-change-type-of-property-via-docorators

In there you can find: "can't do this because the decorator runs at runtime but the type analysis happens at compile time. But"

Comment: Hi, @Kordrad thanks but this is not helpful.